# How do I scan items from other classes in java?

Tags: java

I have a scanner in java and have a class with some JavaFX code. I have a JTextField that takes the user input, but I want to put that user input into my Java scanners. Is there any help I can get? Thanks! (I'm just starting out so please simplify your answer).

Comment: Your question is hard to get. Scanner (if you mean the class) is for reading inputstreams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understood what you mean, it's easy. Just declare the `TextField` and use `TextField` methods to get the input information. It's like this:

```
TextField a;
```

then just do this:

```
String information = a.getText();
```

After that you can use this `String` to print the info:

```
System.out.println(information);
```

I suppose that you've already tied the XML of JavaFX to your controller class:

```
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="YOUR_CONTROLLER"
```